# Custom Adapter Cannot be applied in navigation drawer's fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I want to display custom listview in navigation drawer's fragment page.  However, in my fragment class, I'm getting an error which seems I cannot set a custom adapter.

```
package android_gcm_client.mynavigation;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class List_Fragment extends Fragment {
    View rootview;
    ArrayList prgmName;
public static int [] prgmImages=      {R.drawable.images,R.drawable.images1,R.drawable.images2,R.drawable.images3,R.drawable.images4,R.drawable.images5,R.drawable.images6,R.drawable.images7,R.drawable.images8};
    public static String [] prgmNameList={"Let Us   C","c++","JAVA","Jsp","Microsoft .Net","Android","PHP","Jquery","JavaScript"};

    @Nullable

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootview=inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout,container,false);

        CustomAdapter ca = new CustomAdapter(this,prgmNameList,prgmImages);
        ListView listview=(ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listview.setAdapter(ca);
        return rootview;
    }
}
```

It seems the error happens in line below (custom adapter can not be applied).

```
CustomAdapter ca = new CustomAdapter(this,prgmNameList,prgmImages);
```

In MainActivity I call the fragment as follows:

```
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments

    Fragment objFragment=null;
    switch(position) {
        case 0:
            objFragment=new ListFragment();
            break;
    }

     FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, objFragment)
            .commit();
}
```

I tried different ways to display custom listview for navigation item selected method.

I tried to directly call activity instead of fragment but problem was navigation drawer not visible for all activity. So I tried to call CustomAdapter in activity as I'm doing in fragment.

I have struggle to solve this error. (Sorry for bad English).

Comment: Please, share the exact error you are receiving. Also, did you created the CustomAdapter.java class? This class does not exist in pure Android. So, you have to create it.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `this` in custom adapter. Usually adapters wants a `Context` in constructor call. But this constructor is called inside a fragment and `this` can't be used.

You can use `getActivity()` as Context inside a Fragment. **But. 
Sometimes it can return a `null` if it is called before `onAttach()` of this fragment**.

```
CustomAdapter ca = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), prgmNameList, prgmImages);
```

Also you can use Application context by creating static variable inside your Application class:

```
public class Application extends android.app.Application {
    public static Context AppContext = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        AppContext = getApplicationContext();

        // You can use this line to solve styling problems
        // because Manifest android:theme is not working
        AppContext.setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
    }
}
```

and create adapter like this:

```
CustomAdapter ca = new CustomAdapter(Application.AppContext, prgmNameList, prgmImages);
```